# Excel dates in Office 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-office-2010

In Excel 2010 I have entered thousands of dates using the format `8/12` to indicate August 2012, `1/15` for January 2015, etc.

I need to sort those dates but Excel thinks `8/12` means `August 12` of the current year.
How can I mass correct my entries so Excel will sort the dates based on the month (8) and year (12)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a formula to correct your numbers, e.g. this one:
`=DATE(DAY(B2)+2000,MONTH(B2),1)`

[image]

After converting it, you may want to get rid of the old values:

- select the converted column

  - right click - copy
  - home - paste - values
- delete the original column.